# Scale and color raster legend in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

How can I scale a raster legend so that the legend labels are equally spaced but the values are irregular?

```
## Generate Random Raster
rast <- raster( matrix(
    sample(c(0,10),9, replace=T) + runif(9),
    nrow=3, ncol=3) )
rast[4] <- NA

## legend parameters
zlim  <- c(0,15)
zlabs <- c(0,.1,.25,.5,1, 2.5, 5,10, 15)
zat <- seq(length(zlabs))

## Colors
greycols <- grey(seq(1, 0, length=length(zlabs)+1))

## Plot
raster::plot( rast,
    zlim=zlim,
    breaks=zlabs,
    lab.breaks=zat,
    col=greycols
   # axis.args=list(
   #     at=c(0,zat),
   #     labels=c("NA", zlabs))
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That kind of plot would confuse me tbh

Comment: Because in my case the difference between  .1 and .12 is as important as the difference between 10 and 12

Comment: @Jordan In that case, wouldn’t logging (or some other transformation) of the scale be more appropriate? (That said, it may occasionally make sense to plot untransformed values)

Comment: @Konrad  A logarithmic transformation would only create the equidistant intervals if the data were exponentially distributed, which they are not. Furthermore, any transformation will make it more difficult for my intended audience to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want, a solution could be to store the old values of your raster for the labels, and then change the actual values according to your needs for the plot (so that the color scale and the actual values are matching, while the labels are as you like).

I just use another example and other colors for clarity. In your case, the data transformation would simply be their `rank` as you want equally-spaced intervals:

```
library(raster)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

r = raster(matrix(c(0.75, 0.1, 1.05, 9.8, 9, 1), nrow=2, byrow=T))
zlim = c(0,10)
mycols = c("blue", "red", "green", "magenta", "cyan", "black")
# Convert to DF for ggplot
df = data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
# Transform the data (and rescale to occupy the full zlim space)
df$layer = rescale(rank(r[]), zlim) 
# Plot the "wrong" data, but label them according to the original ones
ggplot() + geom_raster(data=df, aes(y=y, x=x, fill=layer)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = mycols,
                       breaks = df$layer, 
                       labels = r[], 
                       limits = zlim)
```

[image]

I would suggest to use `ggplot2` because it allows for a good amount of control for color scales (see [the online manual](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html)) and because many questions and answers can be found here.
Also, in `scale_fill_gradientn`, the `values` argument can be interesting in some situations - in your case I am not too sure it would meet your needs, but it is worth being aware that this functionality exists.